# Grabbing a piece of a returned match on a regular expression (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I've been learning regular expressions lately and am wondering if this is possible:

I am pulling in a twitter feed and I have access to tweets, but when I want to display those tweets on my web site - links, @ replies and hash tags are all unlinked. So I've begun the process of linking them up. I'm onto the @ replies and have a question:

Here's my regular expression:

```
$content = '@jason is awesome.';
$reply = '/@(\w+)/';

if(preg_match($reply, $content, $matches)){
  var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

So that will return '@jason' but I want to know if there is a way to search for it with the @, but only return what comes after it - just 'jason'. How do I do this with regular expressions?

Comment: Nice. Can you explain to me how that works exactly? Does it store groups in each element of the matches array?

Comment: (With the default flag)
- $matches[0] contains the string matching all the regex
- $matches[1] contains only the first parenthesis ()
- $matches[2] contains only the second, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Double mentioned, $matches[1] will give you want you want.  $matches[0] is special, it contains the whole matching string.  The subsequent items in the list are the captured groups.

Comment: I never knew that's how it worked. I always thought it just dumped the match and that is what you got. This will be very beneficial for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) it appears `$matches[1]` will have the first backreference which in your case should be jason. You can test here: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Answer (score 0):

[Read the #$^&* **Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) I mean.. it's *RIGHT* there...

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   **$matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.**

[image: Picture is worth a thousand words]